# WindowsFormsHost child click event

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, rdp, windowsformshost

Hey I use the RDPCOMAPILib to shadow screens between two computers.
I added a windows forms user control to my project which include the axRDPViewer.

This Control is added to my WPF View in a windowsFormsHost control and works fine, see code:

```
<Grid Name="RDP">
   <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
     <WindowsFormsHost MouseDown="host_MouseDown" PreviewMouseDown="host_PreviewMouseDown" x:Name="host">
        <controls:RDPViewer Click="viewer_Click" MouseClick="viewer_MouseClick" x:Name="viewer"/>              
     </WindowsFormsHost>
   </Border>
</Grid>
```

But none of the click events is raised when I click on the control, but I don't know why?

I want to do something when I doubleclick on the control.

Hope somebody knows a solution to my problem.

Comment: Maybe it helps to think about this a little bit.  Anything you type on the keyboard and any mouse events are passed on to the program that has the foreground on the remote machine.  So of course you cannot see them locally.

Comment: No i think they are not, in normal mode im just in a "viewer mode", so the events are not passed through. Or did i get something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the library or control you're using, but you seem to be missing a `"` in the code you posted. You have

```
MouseClick="viewer_MouseClick x:Name="viewer"
```

but it should be

```
MouseClick="viewer_MouseClick" x:Name="viewer"
```

Comment: :) thx for the hint but that wasnt the problem i just failed to copy it right ^^